# Issue in creating custom directives of marquee of images (using Angular)

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to move marquee of images to a custom directive. Initially in my index file i had a div like below

```
<div id="marquePic" style="width:90%"></div>
```

and later in the script(end of body) I was doing something like below

```
  $(document).ready(function(){


     var picData = [      //image data（json），param：image（image path），title（image title），link（image link）

            {
              image:'http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-33/data1/images/dahlia.jpg',  
              title:'bbb',
              link:'#'
            }, 

            {
              image:'http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-33/data1/images/dahlia.jpg',  
              title:'aa',
              link:'#'
            }
            ];


  $("#marquePic").picMarque({
        speed: 60,//scroll speed（ms）
        errorimg: 'http://www.siaa.org.cn/style/common/nophoto.jpg',//error image path
        data: picData
      });
        });
```

> I am using jQuery PicMarquee.js to get marquee of images.

Doing above i was able to create marquee if images..Later i thought of using angular and move my html code to a separate directive so that i can reuse it.(Please note: For simplicity only  I have only one div with marquee as id.In reality there are few more html elements and hence thought of creating custom directive)

When I create a custom directive above code doesn't work

```
<our-clients></our-clients>
```

and in js i have

```
ourApp.directive('ourClients', function() {
return {
replace: true,
templateUrl: 'directives/clients.html'
};
});
```

clients.html has only data related to marquee eg

```
<div id="marquePic" style="width:90%"></div>
```

and marquee related js(picData etc) is in the original html file which includes my custom directive.

However, after doing above i don't see it working. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide your profile pictures array to your directive and let it process those and call your third party library.
Also I'd not use id for that if you want to make a directive for it.

Controller:

```
$scope.picData = [{... images here ...}, {...}]
```

In Directive:

```
ourApp.directive('ourClients', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'directives/clients.html',
        scope: {
            images: '='
        }
        link: function($scope, element){
            //or just use $(element).picMargue
            $(element).find('.marquePic').picMarque({
                speed: 60,//scroll speed（ms）
                errorimg: 'http://www.siaa.org.cn/style/common/nophoto.jpg',//error image path
                data: $scope.images
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Directive html:

```
<div>
    <div class="marquePic"></div>
</div>
```

Call it:

```
<our-clients images="picData"></our-clients>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is some issue with above code.First i think link method should take "scope" as a parameter and "data should be data:scope.picData  instead of $scope.picData

However,after making above changes i get another error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined"

Comment: sure I fixed few things right before you wrote this comment.

Comment: it should work, i don't know where your issue is but I guess you can debug it and see what causing the issue. But the concept is there what was basically your question. Did you wrapped your directive's html content into an additional div as I did in the example right?

Comment: thanks..yeah i will debug and check. Anyways, you explained the concept very well.

Comment: Sure sure :-). Your explanation really helped. Needs really lot of patience for reading such long questions and answering. Highly appreciated.